# Table heights rendering across in html email?

Tags: html, css, email

I'm almost done with a new email template for eblasts, I've used simple html with tables and inline css throughout. It renders fine in Outlook, and Yahoo Mail. But in gmail and while opening on mobile, two tables that I designed as buttons dimensions render differently. It doesn't seem to be reading the height. How could I get the dimensions to render at least closely across?

```
<table width="110" align="left" border="0" height="15" style="width:100px; background-color:#EEF1C2; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center;">
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: GMail's mobile view is known to be awful. I once programmed a newsletter system, and because of bad rendering in Gmail I put a "View In Website" option in all of the messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the CSS attribute `min-height`?

Comment: Not precisely. But I like your thought process and I cannot delete this. Point to you, sir Tim.